# DockerのUbuntuコンテナでLAMP環境の構築をシェルスクリプトで自動化させたいです

Tags: ubuntu, shellscript

DockerのUbuntuコンテナでLAMP環境の構築をシェルスクリプトで自動化させたいです。
以下の手順で環境構築するらしいですが、一部質問するために、省略したり、改変している部分（。。。。。にしたり）があります。

**質問項目**

- それぞれのコードの%と$の違い
- ②のデーモン起動　⑧のxvfbの起動って必要な作業ですか？（起動させないと不都合があるのでしょうか）
- ⑩⑪⑫のやっている内容が知識不足で理解できません
- ⑤と⑬に関して、通常の手法をコード付きで教えてください（設定ファイルを別に作っておいて上書きするのか、該当部分だけ書き換えるのか）
- dockerに関して、通常チームで開発する際、どの順序で使うのでしょうか（イメージ作る->イメージをメンバーに配る->各人がそのイメージを使ってコンテナを作成->コンテナで作業した変更内容はcommitで別イメージとして保存->ここからの流れがわかりません。また、ここまでの流れはあってますか？）どのようにして変更内容を統合させるのでしょうか(Gitで言うmerge？)

**環境構築手順**

1. 基本システムのインストール

   ```
   % apt-get install php composer apache2 mysql-server supervisor
   ```
2. デーモンを起動

   ```
   % service apache2 start
   % service supervisor start
   ```
3. PHPの追加機能のインストール

   ```
   % apt-get install php7.0-mysqlなど
   ```
4. Apache module有効

   ```
   % a2enmod ssl
   % a2enmod php7.0
   % a2enmod rewrite
   % service apache2 restart
   ```
5. `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`の該当部分を以下に変更

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
           AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ```
6. nodejsのインストール

   ```
   % curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/xxxxxx.x | bash -
   % apt-get install nodejs
   ```
7. xvfb関連ライブラリをインストール

   ```
   % apt-get install libgtk xvfb
   ```
8. xvfb起動

   ```
   $ Xvfb 。。。。。。。
   ```
9. 各種ライブラリをインストール

   ```
   $ cd /var/www/。。。。。
   $ npm install
   $ cd /var/www/。。。。。
   $ composer install
   ```
10. envファイルを作る

    ```
    $ cd /var/www/。。。。。
    $ cp .env.example .env
    ```
11. 一時フォルダのパーミッションを設定
    cdで移動し、別ディレクトリにそれぞれ設定

    ```
    $ chmod 1777
    ```
12. supervisorの設定（リンク？）

    ```
    % ln -s 。。。。。。laravel-worker.conf
    ```
13. Apacheのドキュメントルートを変更 
    `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`の該当部分をいかに変更

    ```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/。。。。。
    ```

Comment: どうしてもvimを使わないとダメですか？単に任意のtextをファイルへ出力したいだけではないですか？

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi  その通りです。それがしたいです。設定ファイル？をシェルスクリプトから編集したいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「自動化したい」ということなので、まずはいま手作業で実施(実行)している項目を挙げて、代わりにここを変数にして置き換えたい、など具体的な情報を追記できませんか。

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi　質問内容を修正したので、教えて下さい

Answer (score 1):

回答できるところまで書きます。

> ・それぞれのコードの%と$の違い

実行ユーザーがroot と一般ユーザーの違い。rootが％と一般ユーザー＄です。

> ・②のデーモン起動　⑧のxvfbの起動って必要な作業ですか？（起動させないと不都合があるのでしょうか）

デーモンプログラムを起動しないと使用するときに動きません。

> ・⑩⑪⑫のやっている内容が知識不足で理解できません

⑪ chmodで実行権限を変更します。書き込みや実行できるようにします。

> ・⑤と⑬に関して、通常の手法をコード付きで教えてください（設定ファイルを別に作っておいて上書きするのか、該当部分だけ書き換えるのか）

両方とも使います。部分的な書き換えはsedコマンド、 ファイルの置き換えはcatコマンドを使用してください。
sedについて参考になりそうなサイト
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ja/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/manip_strings_sed.htm

スクリプト全般で参考になりそうなサイト
http://blog.hitsujin.jp/entry/2011/03/09/140329

Comment: 質問内容を追記したので、教えてください。お願いします

Answer (score 1):

シェルスクリプトで設定ファイルを作りたいのですね。
cat を使ってファイルを作ることができます。

```
cat <<EOF > 作成するファイル名
  ファイルの内容を記述
    ：：：：
     ：：：：
EOF
```

シェルスクリプトのサンプル：

```
#!/bin/bash

# 作成するファイル名のフルパスを変数にセット
NEW_FILE=/var/hoge/foo/bar.txt

# ファイルのディレクトリを抜き出して変数にセット
DIRECTORY="$(dirname $NEW_FILE )"

# ディレクトリを作成
mkdir -p "$DIRECTORY"

# ディレクトリに移動
cd "$DIRECTORY"

# ファイルを作成 (既に有れば上書き)
cat <<EOF > $NEW_FILE
!! ここに設定ファイルの内容を書きます。!!
!! 変数は次のように書くと値に展開されます。!!
${NEW_FILE}
!! この↓のEOFの直前(すなわちこの行)までがファイルに書かれます。!!
EOF

# 直前のディレクトリに戻る
cd -
```

実際にスクリプトを実行して、作成されたファイルを表示すると次のようになるはずです。

```
$ bash ./sample.sh
$ cat /var/hoge/foo/bar.txt
!! ここに設定ファイルの内容を書きます。!!
!! 変数は次のように書くと値に展開されます。!!
/var/hoge/foo/bar.txt
!! この↓のEOFの直前(すなわちこの行)までがファイルに書かれます。!!
```

---

(追記)

> ②のデーモン起動　⑧のxvfbの起動って必要な作業ですか？（起動させないと不都合があるのでしょうか）

apache2 は起動させないと LAMP環境が動きません。
xvfb の用途がわかりませんがたぶん、ブラウザテスト用途でしょうか。使いたいなら動かしてください。

> ⑩⑪⑫のやっている内容が知識不足で理解できません

⑩ : .env.example というファイルを /var/www/.... にコピーしてます。内容がわかりませんので .env.example のファイルの内容を確認してみてください。
⑪ : ディレクトリのパーミッションを設定してます。`1777` はすべてのユーザに読み書き権限を与えますが、オーナーしか削除はできないというモードです。(スティッキービットと言います)
⑫ : シンボリックリンクを作成しています。

> ⑤と⑬に関して、通常の手法をコード付きで教えてください（設定ファイルを別に作っておいて上書きするのか、該当部分だけ書き換えるのか）

⑤ : 色々やり方はあると思いますのでどちらが良いとも言えません。なので個人的な好みをご紹介しますと、複数行の書き換えは若干面倒くさい気もするので、設定ファイルを新規に作るのが個人的には好みです。ついでにコメントアウトも邪魔なので消しちゃいますね。

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apache2/apache.conf
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
EOF
```

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName 1.2.3.4:443
        DocumentRoot /var/www/...........
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
    <Location /devbox>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:4200/
    </Location>
</IfModule>
EOF
```

> dockerに関して、通常チームで開発する際、どの順序で使うのでしょうか（イメージ作る->イメージをメンバーに配る->各人がそのイメージを使ってコンテナを作成->コンテナで作業した変更内容はcommitで別イメージとして保存->ここからの流れがわかりません。また、ここまでの流れはあってますか？）どのようにして変更内容を統合させるのでしょうか(Gitで言うmerge？)

ご自身で書かれてますが、git などのバージョン管理ソフトを使って、ブランチを分けて開発して、マージしていくのが一般的だと思います。

Comment: 質問内容を追記したので、教えてください。お願いします